# Do Python Inline if statements execute a function twice?

Tags: python

When I do something like (totally random example dont read into variable names):

```
variable = read_file() if read_file() else "File was empty"
```

In this case does read_file() get excuted twice? If so is there a way to do it to only execute once but keep it within one line?

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to do this; how does the code that uses `variable` know that the file didn't actually contain `"File was empty"`?

Comment: Again totally random variable/method names

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In that case `read_file()` would get executed twice. You can do this instead:

```
variable = read_file() or "File was empty"
```